# Custom Emma report generation

Tags: java, code-coverage, emma

Is there a way to generate a custom report for EMMA.  What I am looking to do is create an html report that groups the java packages view into a functional component area so that I can see a report driven by functional component instead of package.

for Example say I have

Feature A
com.a.a
com.a.b

Feature B
com.b.a
com.b.a

The report would be configured to show the coverage on Feature A and Feature B instead of the underlying packages.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see [from the documentation](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference_single/reference.html#prop-ref), there's no such a feature. What you can do, though, is to add a post-processor which would take EMMA reports and restructure those at you prefer: EMMA provides a handy [XML format](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch02s04s02.html) which is easy to consume.